# PHP - UTF-8 Characters showing as ? and �

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

First of all, thanks for taking your time to look at this. Text from my database tables is being printed with a question mark or � for symbols like č, ę, ė, į, ų, ū, ž etc...

What I've tried:

- Setting `default_charset "utf-8"` in my `php.ini`.
- Setting meta tags.
- Using `mb_detect_encoding($mystring, "UTF-8, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2)` on a string returns iso-8859-1. BUT collation in my DB is set to utf8. And the symbols in the text should be UTF8 (Lithuanian).
- Setting charset to iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-2 in `php.ini` loads SOME symbols, but still lots of them are question marks, although the black squares disappear. I also used Windows-1252, didn't help.

  - I also checked the files in Notepad++, for the encodin, and they seem to be UTF-8 without BOM.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z7w5.png)

If I do this the text disappears altogether:

```
iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF8',$string)
```

I ran out of ideas on what to do, help me. I'll give any more info I can provide.

Comment: If you're using PDO, have you tried `new PDO( $dsn, $user, $pass, [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND  => "SET NAMES utf8" ] )`?

Comment: is being printed where? a webpage? a console?

Comment: @pvg a website, sorry.

Comment: @chris85 YES. THANKS. It helped! Oh man. I was googling for like 3+ hours before asking. Thanks again!!!!